# Set up two multi-stage builds without repeating yourself

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My application is built using a multi-stage build in the following way.

**Dockerfile 1**

```
FROM debian:stretch as prebuilder
# Define the prebuilder
FROM prebuilder as build-stage
# Build app 1
FROM build-stage as run-stage
# Copy app 1 from build-stage and setup runtime environment
```

**Dockerfile 2**

```
FROM debian:stretch as prebuilder
# Define the prebuilder
FROM prebuilder as build-stage
# Build app 2
FROM build-stage as run-stage
# Copy app 2 from build-stage and setup runtime environment
```

The problem is that the `prebuilder` and `run-stage` are identical in app 1 and app 2 (except for the actual app files that are copied over from the `build-stage` to the `run-stage`. So I'm repeating myself unnecessarily in both Dockerfiles.

Are there any built-in constructs in Docker multi-stage builds to start a build stage using a build stage from another image (even though it's not the final stage)?

Thanks!

Comment: If we define the `prebuild` in its own dockerfile and push it as separate image, we can use it in both dockerfiles.

Comment: "except for the actual app files that are copied" please expand your example Dockerfiles to show this. It's not clear if the stage is the same and you copy different files out, or you are creating a different stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official Docker [registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry) for local image registry platform.

This is how you can go about it:

1. Build your **redundant/shared** parent image
2. Push it to your docker registry(if you have any scopes or environment
   you can push it as per your
   scope/environment)
3. Use it in the other docker files as a base image